# Не удаляются спецсимволы в строке

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

Делаю парсинг сайта https://carrol.ru
выбираю из таблицы нужные данные, преобразую в строку, которая выводится var_dump на экран как обычная строка без спецсимволов, 
но при копировании ее (мышкой) получается много мусора, попробуйте скопировать в текстовый редактор строку ниже и увидите непонятные символы:

'LX307,MAHLE ГЕРМАНИЯ,,SUBARU,

я посмотрел исходный код страницы и увидел символы &#13

пытаюсь сделать замену через str_replace:

```
$dirty_result = str_replace("&#13;", "", $dirty_result);
```

также пробовал через регулярку:

```
$dirty_result = preg_replace('~[^A-Za-z0-9а-пА-Пр-яР-ЯёЁ\s,;-]~','', $dirty_result);
```

Но символы всеравно остаются.

как удалить эти символы, чтобы была обычная строка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Символ `&#13`, это ASCII символ возврата каретки. Попробуйте заменить способом ниже. Если не поможет, буду думать дальше.

`$dirty_result = str_replace("\r", "", $dirty_result);`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!